# How to pass data object from one method to another in Typescript

Tags: c#, angular, typescript

My question might sound ugly but am trying to learn Typescript. I have created three different methods that return data and I am assigning all the returned data to the object (any) so that I can bind it to on client side. All that is working fine with one method having a hardcoded value which is not right.

I have nested **getOverridelist()** and **getDiscountedRates()** under **getDetails** method which i am calling it on **ngOnInit()**

Under class **OnInit** , I have declared

```
public myOveride: any = {};
public myDiscount: any = {};

ngOnInit() {

    this.getDetails();
}
```

Method: this method is being passed on

```
getDetails() {
    
    this.myService.getDetails(ID).then(data => {
        if (data != undefined) {
            this.seller = data;
            this.getOverridelist();
            this.getDiscountedRates();
        } else {
            -----------
        }
        this.isLoading = false;
        this.error = false;
        })
        .catch(error => {
            this.error = true;
            this.errorMsg = 'Error';
            this.isLoading = false;
        });
}
```

The method below returns a data object which I then pump to  **myOveride: any**. from the returned data, i want to get **returnedId** and pass/use it under this getDiscountedRates(); I will also use some of the fields too.

```
getOverridelist() {

    var customerId = this.seller.customer;
    this.isLoading = true;
    this.myService.getOverridelist(customerId).then(dataObject => {
        this.myOveride = dataObject;
    }).catch(error => {
        this.error = true;
        this.errorMsg = 'Error';
        this.isLoading = false;
    });
}
```

**dataObject** returns data and I want to use Id returned here. I want to use it on this function.

```
 getDiscountedRates() {
    var overrideId = 261; // I want to remove this hardcoded Id.
    this.isLoading = true;
    this.myService.getDiscountedRates(overrideId).then(dataObjec => {
        this.myDiscount = dataObjec;
    }).catch(error => {
        this.error = true;
        this.errorMsg = 'Error';
        this.isLoading = false;
    });
}
```

How do I get pass data object from one method to another in typeScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to answer your question

> How to pass data object from one method to another in Typescript

you can simply add the data as a parameter on your function:

```
getDiscountedRates(dataObject: any) {
  ...
}
```

An issue here might arise because you are calling `getDiscountedRates` from `getDetails`, and before you actually have the `dataObject` (because that object returns from the `getOverridelist` response. My suggestion is to trigger `getDiscountedRates` from `getOverridelist` and either pass the object or check `this.myOverride` has an ID before accessing it (since you initialize it to an empty object).

So something like the following:
getOverridelist() {

```
var customerId = this.seller.customer;
this.isLoading = true;
this.myService.getOverridelist(customerId).then(dataObject => {
    this.myOveride = dataObject;
    this.getDiscountedRates(dataObject);
}).catch(error => {
    this.error = true;
    this.errorMsg = 'Error';
    this.isLoading = false;
});
}

getDiscountedRates(dataObject) {
    this.isLoading = true;
    this.myService.getDiscountedRates(dataObject.id).then(dataObjec => {
        this.myDiscount = dataObjec;
    }).catch(error => {
        this.error = true;
        this.errorMsg = 'Error';
        this.isLoading = false;
    });
}
```